# HTML5 Conformance Checker

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I got the following warning using the W3C validator:

> Using experimental feature: HTML5 Conformance Checker

What exactly does it mean? That I can't count on this validator?

Comment: that's same error we get when give w3c the address of stackoverflow! LOL :P

Answer (score 31):

The warning "Using experimental feature: HTML5 Conformance Checker." means that the validator is checking your markup as HTML5, but since the w3c hasn't agreed on every part of the HTML5 standard, you should take what the validator says with a grain of salt, because it is prone to change until the standard is complete. The warning does not mean that there is anything wrong with your code, but if you want to get rid of the warning, try validating with a Doctype of "HTML 4.01 Strict".

Comment: If you test with <!DOCTYPE HTML>, you'll get the HTML5 checker. If you use <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> or another valid doctype, you will not.

Comment: There is also an option on the w3c validator to change which doctype you validate against regardless of which doctype is used in your document.

Answer (score 5):

HTML5 is an unfinished draft so the validator is:

- New and subject to more bugs than one that has been in production for years (since HTML5 has abandoned the SGML legacy of its predecessors--you can't just use a DTD based validator)
- Comparing your document to a moving target (which might have fallen behind)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Ronnie says, I tend to use [HTML5 Validator](http://html5.validator.nu/) which doesn't give you that message, but it is of course also still experimental although things are unlikely to change much in the HTML5 specification at this stage I believe.

Answer (score 0):

It means the there are no issues with your code, however the document may or may not be semantically correct.

check out this article http://www.alistapart.com/articles/semanticsinhtml5/